# Is it safe to drink water from a bottle after exposure to xrays?

Tags: medical-science

Is it safe to drink water that was in an insulated water bottle that was directly in front of an X-ray machine with no lead barrier in between?

Comment: I doubt the X-ray would have an effect on the water itself--if there were any effect it would be from X-rays' interaction with the materials in the bottle, which would depend on the composition of your bottle.

Comment: This question isn't really challenging a claim though, just asking a science question. Maybe it should be migrated to one of the science sites.

Comment: Irradiation is sometimes used to make materials sterile to produce shelf-stable versions of things that are normally perishable.  An x-ray is going to do even less to water than to food.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: Note: Initially, I was tempted to leave this open, because fear of irradiated food seems common enough to be notable, and it quickly earned an answer. But the answer is addressing the water *only*, and not any effect of x-rays on the bottle, but I don't feel I can make that comment on the answer because it isn't clear if that is part of the question. I would like to clear this up with a notability reference.

Answer (score 2):

The water will be perfectly safe.

X-rays are used to inspect many forms of food, as detailed by the [European Food Information Council](http://www.eufic.org/article/en/artid/X-rays-in-food-inspection/), and it is generally considered safe.

Food is sometimes [sterilised](http://Food%20irradiation) with X-rays or even gamma rays, which have higher energy than X-rays. In both cases the food is considered perfectly safe for consumption.

As for the [effect of X-rays on water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_damage), remember that water is used as a cooling fluid in nuclear reactors. While the radiation can dissociate water molecules, it has very little effect on the nuclei of hydrogen and oxygen atoms. The products of dissociation are mostly gaseous, and, while they are reactive (for example, oxygen) they will mostly escape the water or recombine to form other molecules, the worst of which is hydrogen peroxide (used to bleach hair). However, it requires major doses of radiation for any of these effects to occur.

X-rays are also used to inspect your luggage when you fly, and all your food and equipment are still safe afterwards.

Comment: They used to warn not to put undeveloped photographic film in your luggage, because X-rays were bad for it.  But how many readers here have ever even *seen* photographic film?

Comment: And film is one item that is sensitive to x-rays. And, of course, the film is still safe to handle afterwards ;-)

Comment: The container is heavy duty plastic

Comment: So don't worry about the container.